# XP fresh install no display driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, display, reinstall

I just did a fresh install of XP and have done all of my updates. I cannot get the driver to install. I have tried the disk. It just has a setup page that opens in a browser. There is now driver anywhere on the disk that I can see. I have also installed the driver from their website. It installs in C:\Dell\Drivers. I tried running that and nothing happens. It just opens the folder. It has 3 files: a `.cat` an `.icm` and a `.inf`. If I go into the display properties for windows I do not have an option for 1080p (which is the monitor). How can I resolve this? It worked previously before the fresh install. The monitor is a Dell `E2311H`.

Answer (score 0):

To install an INF, you go to device manager, right click the display driver which should have an exclamation mark, look for anything with exclamation marks, they may be listed in 'other devices' and go to update driver and point it to the location of the INF file.

If you can't do that then next best thing is right click the INF and click install.

Comment: To OP, It's good that you tried the dell website (presumably the support section and you entered the service tag and let it find the drivers for your machine) and you tried the disc too. (one of the two, -if I recall, it was the website with service tag- is slightly better,giving only the drivers for your machine specifically).